# Python - load and use new process multiple times with different arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing, celery, gil

I wanna create a seperate python process with loaded functions, which can be acessed/used/called later with different arguments multiple times (to overcome **GIL**). This is kind of like `multiprocessing`, but creating a new process via `multiprocessing` is too slow, because (*as I understood*) the process is unloaded after its execution. I'm not sure what exactly do I need to use.

**How can I start a process multiple times with different args without a need to create it again?**

I tried using `multiprocessing`, but I can't use it several times (`AssertionError: cannot start a process twice`). I also checked `celery`, but I'm not sure if this is the right way

**Example:**

```py
from multiprocessing import Process


def add(a, b):
    print(a + b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=add, args=(5, 5))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    p.start()  # Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate Python script that loads the necessary functions and runs a loop to listen for incoming requests. Then communicate with this script from main process using a suitable interprocess communication mechanism such as pipes, sockets, or shared memory.

1. Create a separate worker.py script, which defines the functions you want to use and listens for incoming requests:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def worker():
    while True:
        task, args = q.get()
        if task == 'add':
            result = foo(*args)
            q.put(result)
        else:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=worker)
    p.start()
```

2. In main process, you can communicate with the worker process by putting tasks and arguments onto the queue, and waiting for results to come back:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=worker)
    p.start()

    q.put(('add', [5, 5]))  # Compute add(5, 5)
    result = q.get()    # Get the result (10)

    q.put(('add', [3, 3]))  # Compute bar(3, 3)
    result = q.get()    # Get the result (6)

    q.put(('stop', []))  # Stop the worker process
    p.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will probably also use multiprocessing with async and create await event, so it will wait for an event before starting again. (so I don't need to use while True)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that does this process invocation, then call it in a loop as many times as you want.

Comment: The main problem is that, creating a new process is really slow. I wanna find a way to declare process and just call it, not "create, start, close, start again" (slow)

Answer (score 0):

Use a multiprocessing pool, which creates a number of processes (default = number of CPUs) that can be submitted tasks.  In this case, [`starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) will do what you want:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def task(a, b):
    return a + b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        args = (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 7), (10, 20)
        print(pool.starmap(task, args))
```

Output:

```
[3, 7, 12, 30]
```